# Non-invocable member 'OperationResult' cannot be used like a method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

i have this class for return date :

```
 public class OperationResult<TResult>
{
    public TResult Result { get; private set; }
    public bool Success { get; private set; }
    public string ErrorMessage { get; private set; } = null;
    public Exception Exception { get; private set; } = null;

    public static OperationResult<TResult> BuildSuccessResult(TResult result)
    {
        return new OperationResult<TResult> { Success = true, Result = result };

    }

    public static OperationResult<TResult> BuildFailure(string errorMessage)
    {
        return new OperationResult<TResult> { Success = false, ErrorMessage = errorMessage };

    }
    public static OperationResult<TResult> BuildFailure(Exception ex)
    {
        return new OperationResult<TResult> { Success = false, Exception = ex };
    }

    public static OperationResult<TResult> BuildFailure(Exception ex, string errorMessage)
    {
        return new OperationResult<TResult> { Success = false, Exception = ex, ErrorMessage = errorMessage };
    }
}
```

i use this for result of function :

```
        public async Task<OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>> GetAll<TResult>(string spName)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection(configration.ReportingConnection))
        {
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                var query = await connection.QueryAsync<TResult>(spName);
                if (query != null)
                {
                    var res=  OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>().BuildSuccessResult(query);
                }
                return new OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>().BuildFailure("Error When Getting Date form DateBase");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return  OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>().BuildFailure(ex,"");

            }
            finally
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

but it show me this error in this line :

> Non-invocable member 'OperationResult' cannot be used like a method.

in this line :

`var res=  OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>().BuildSuccessResult(query);`

or show this error

> Member 'OperationResult>.BuildFailure(string)' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead    AdminPanelGetWay.DAL.Dapper

in this line

`return new OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>().BuildFailure("Error When Getting Date form DateBase");`

**now whats the problem ? how can i solve this problem ????**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because your methods are all static. Instead of

```
var res=  OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>().BuildSuccessResult(query);
```

You need to remove "()"

```
var res=  OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>.BuildSuccessResult(query);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call `static` methods in a class, you don't need to create objects of this class.

You can call the static method inside the class directly with the class name.(refer to [this](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-static))

Change the two sentences with the error to the following:

```
    //....
    var res = OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>.BuildSuccessResult(query); 
    //....
    return OperationResult<IEnumerable<TResult>>.BuildFailure("Error When Getting Date form DateBase");
    //....
```